# IBM Watson does not parse json payload from python requests correctly (400)

Tags: python, http, python-requests, ibm-watson

I want to make an API call to the following endpoint https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#send-user-input-to-assistant

My code looks as follows:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = (WATSON_USERNAME, WATSON_PASSWORD)
data = { "input" : {"text" :"my message"} }
response = session.post(
    f'{WATSON_ENDPOINT}/{session_id}/message?{WATSON_API_VER}', 
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    data=data)
```

The response I get from watson is

```
{ "error": "Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0", "code":400 }
```

If i change `data` to `{ "X" : {"text" :"my message"} }`

```
{ "error": "Unexpected token X in JSON at position 0", "code":400 }
```

Any idea on why my `data` payload can't be parsed like the example the API provides?

Comment: You are form encoding data instead of JSON encoding. Change the `data` parameter to `json` like so. `r = session.post(endpoint, headers={'content-type': 'application/json', json=data)`

Comment: @alxgmpr   There's no need to set `Content-Type` manually

Comment: @IvanVinogradov I know I was just being redundant mimicking the code that he had already posted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json=` parameter to `POST` a JSON with requests.

It will automatically encode your data and add `Content-Type: application/json` header.

```py
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = (WATSON_USERNAME, WATSON_PASSWORD)

data = {"input": {"text": "my message"}}
url = f'{WATSON_ENDPOINT}/{session_id}/message?{WATSON_API_VER}'

response = session.post(url, json=data)
print(response.status_code, response.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

This `data` payload you are sending is a Python `dict`, which `Requests` will encode as POST data

```
data = { "input" : {"text" :"my message"} }
```

The API you are talking to wants JSON data

```
import data
data = json.dumps(data)
```

It looks like you built the example from the sidebar

```
curl -u "apikey:{apikey}" -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"input\": {\"text\": \"Hello\"}}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/assistants/{assistant_id}/sessions/{session_id}/message?version=2019-02-28"
```

the data sent to `curl` is a string of encoded JSON.

If you go back to that example url, there is a dropdown that shows you how to make requests in `Python` with the `ibm_watson` package.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data = { "input" : {"text" :"my message"} }
>>> data
{'input': {'text': 'my message'}}
>>> type(data)
<class 'dict'>
```

Here is what the python shell gives me from your code regarding the variable called `data`.

You likely need a string though, not a dictionary.

```
>>> myvar = '{ "input" : {"text" :"my message"} }'
>>> myvar
'{ "input" : {"text" :"my message"} }'
>>> type(myvar)
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Python requests(data={a_dictionary}) automatically serializes the data dictionary into a json string which is then sent over in the request as the payload. A json string would cause a runtime error. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: As per Jonathan s answer my understanding of how requests works is incorrect in my previous comment, but im leaving it up for documentation

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood me, perhaps I got it wrong. I did not dive in too deep. But I'm pretty sure your error stems from the fact that it expected quotes before your `input`

Comment: `requests.post(json={a_dictionary})` can submit json encoded data as the post body - but you have to pass it in as `json` not `data`.   simply posting `data` uses HTTP POST encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the Watson Python SDK?

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

It will handle all these niggling details for you.